# Develop application with different resolution for mobile and tablet?

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-drawable, screen-resolution, screen-density

I want to develop application which should support android mobile resolution as well as tablet resolution.There are some question at time development we should know.

Q1) What is different between density and resolution?

Q2) Designer generally design application in pixel (1440x2560)
how designer will take care of density what should he have to take care at time of design?

Q3) What is the `best` way to handle font size for different resolution/density?

Q3) Which drawable folder is represent which device resolution/density?

Q4) Application Launcher icon size for different resolution/density?

Q5) Notification icon/Statusbar icon size for different resolution/density?

Answer (score 1):

> Q1) What is different between density and resolution?

Your Answer is in [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

> **Resolution**   The total number of physical pixels on a screen. When adding support for multiple screens, applications do not work directly
>   with resolution; applications should be concerned only with screen
>   size and density, as specified by the generalized size and density
>   groups.
>
> **Density-independent pixel (dp)**   A virtual pixel unit that you should use when defining UI layout, to express layout dimensions or
>   position in a density-independent way. The density-independent pixel
>   is equivalent to one physical pixel on a 160 dpi screen, which is the
>   baseline density assumed by the system for a "medium" density screen.
>   At runtime, the system transparently handles any scaling of the dp
>   units, as necessary, based on the actual density of the screen in use.
>   The conversion of dp units to screen pixels is simple: px = dp * (dpi
>   / 160). For example, on a 240 dpi screen, 1 dp equals 1.5 physical
>   pixels. You should always use dp units when defining your
>   application's UI, to ensure proper display of your UI on screens with
>   different densities.

Then

> Q2) Designer generally design application in pixel (1440x2560) how
>   designer will take care of density what should he have to take care at
>   time of design?

They can use converters like [this](https://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter/) to design appropriate designs.

> Q3) What is the best way to handle font size for different
>   resolution/density?

You should use `Scale independent pixels(sp)` unit for your fonts.

> Q3) Which drawable folder is represent which device
>   resolution/density?

Answer to this is again in [Official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

> Q4) Application Launcher icon size for different resolution/density?
>
> Q5) Notification icon/Statusbar icon size for different
>   resolution/density?

You can create your icons for different resolutions using [this](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/)